# ImageButton is 'null' after assignment

Tags: java, android, android-button

This is my first time creating an Android app, and I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I'm trying to point an ImageButton variable to an existing `ImageButton` by ID, but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`. Here's the code:

```
    ...
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        ImageButton addButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
                addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_category_button);
        }...
```

The `ImageButton` is located in the layout `card_categories`. Here's the XML for that layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/main_page"
android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_category_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/add_button"
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure if the issue is an improper `id`, or what, but it's not pulling the `ImageButton` in the XML correctly. Thanks for your help!

**Update**: I tried assigning the `ImageButton` after `setContentView(R.layout.card_categories)` , but it still is null.

```
OnClickListener myCardsHandler = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.card_categories);
        addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_category_button);
        loadCategories(dbHandler, categories);
    }
};
```

Comment: _"The ImageButton is located in the layout card_categories"_ but you are inflating `R.layout.activity_start` so how would you expect to get your `ImageButton`?

Comment: Make sure: `activity_start.xml` contains that `ImageButton`. I think you may `setContentView` to different layout.

Comment: You are assigning it in the OnClickListener buddy :) this should ideally happen in the Activity#OnCreate lifecycle method !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.card_categories);
       addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_category_button);
       addButton.setOnClickListener(myCardsHandler);
   }

   OnClickListener myCardsHandler = new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {

           loadCategories(dbHandler, categories);
       }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the wrong layout in your `setContentView` method. So it's not surprising, that the compiler will not find any `ImageButton` of that name there.

Either inflate card_categories:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
```

or place your `ImageButton` in the layout you have currently set.

Comment: I moved it to after I call the new     setContentView(R.layout.card_categories) but it still gives me a Null value for addButton